# Configure Custom Role for Contributor to Resources based on name pattern

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I am looking at way to delegate contributor / owner permissions to resource groups lifecycle based on name pattern of the group.  I am having trouble finding the proper approach.
In custom role definition, there does not seem to be an easy way to assign Actions to resource type based on name pattern, while in azure policy definition i do not see a way to query user principal to determine a role of a user making an access action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Policy is not user aware,  so you will not be able to get that information and enforce it.

Comment: A better approach is to create a custom role that allows read/write of role assignments

Answer (score 1):

As a different approach, you could listen for the resource group creation events with event grid, and assign the relevant roles based on the events.

https://www.serverlessnotes.com/docs/detect-changes-in-your-azure-subscriptions-or-resource-groups-with-azure-event-grid

You could use Logic Apps or Azure Functions to achieve your result, although I am unsure how easy it will be to get Logic Apps to set role assignments on your resource groups.

You will need to give this automation process some fairly high permissions to achieve that, so be wary of that.

Comment: Thank you for an alternative opinion. I thought about automation to do this, and event grid is a great push model approach.